# ASP.Net MVC: Selected country id value in dropdown not passing to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have webgrid where i am showing student data like ID, name and student country. all data is in editable format. country data appear in dropdown.

my UI

[image]

here is my controller code

```
public class WebGridMoreControlsController : Controller
{
    // GET: WebGridMoreControls
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StudentListViewModel osvm = new StudentListViewModel();
        return View(osvm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(StudentListViewModel oStudentListViewModel)
    {
        return View(oStudentListViewModel);
    }
}
```

here is my model code

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

viewmodel code

```
public class StudentListViewModel
{
    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCountryId { set; get; }
    public List<Country> Country { get; set; }

    public StudentListViewModel()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student{ID=1,Name="Keith",CountryID=1},
            new Student{ID=2,Name="Paul",CountryID=2},
            new Student{ID=3,Name="Sam",CountryID=3}
        };

        Country = new List<Country>
        {
            new Country{ID=1,Name="India"},
            new Country{ID=2,Name="UK"},
            new Country{ID=3,Name="USA"}


        };
    }
}
```

here is my razor view code

```
@model MVCCRUDPageList.Models.StudentListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Student View Model</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "WebGridMoreControls", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Students, canSort: false, canPage: false);
    var rowNum = 0;


    <div id="gridContent" style=" padding:20px; ">
        @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "table",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternate",
        selectedRowStyle: "selected",
        headerStyle: "header",
        columns: grid.Columns
        (
            grid.Column(null, null, format: item => rowNum = rowNum + 1),
            grid.Column("ID", format: (item) => @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Students[rowNum - 1].ID, new { @class = "edit-mode" })),
            grid.Column("Name", format: (item) => @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Students[rowNum - 1].Name, new { @class = "edit-mode" })),

             grid.Column("Country", format: (item) => 
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountryId,
                  new SelectList(Model.Country, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCountryId = item.CountryID), 
                 "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboCountry", @class = "edit-mode" }))
        ))
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

}
```

where did i made the mistake for which changed country ID from drowdown not getting pass to action when i submit form. country id is also 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Student` model contains a property `CountryID` which is the property you need to bind to. Remove the `public int SelectedCountryId { set; get; }` property from your view model, and change the code in the view to bind to `CountryID`

```
grid.Column("Country", format: (item) => 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Students[rowNum - 1].CountryID, 
        new SelectList(Model.Country, "ID", "Name", item.CountryID), 
        "-- Select States--",
        new { @class = "edit-mode" }
    )
)
```

In addition, remove the `new { id = "cboCountry" }` from the `DropDownListFor()` method which is generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes)

Note you current code binds the value of the selected option in each `<select>` to your `SelectedCountryId` property, but the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first value in the request, so the value of `SelectedCountryId` would be the value of the selected option in the first row (i.e. the ID associated with 'India' in your image).